# Change represented Days and Months in DatePicker

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker, java-time

I need to add Jalali Calendar to my JavaFX application. I have already extended Chronology class and have added JalaliChronology to my application. When I use the following block of code, it correctly detects what day of what month of what year we're at.

```
DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();

Locale.setDefault(new Locale("fa"));
datePicker.setChronology(JalaliChronology.INSTANCE);
```

But, I need to use the actual name of months and days used in Jalali Calendar. Right now I see `January` as the first month of each year while I want to replace it with `فروردین`.

the following picture that I borrowed from internet tells me that it should be doable but I couldn't yet figure out how.

[image]

Also, I know that I can modify the display text of each cell inside my calendar using following block

```
final Callback<DatePicker, DateCell> dayCells = new Callback<DatePicker, DateCell>()
{
    public DateCell call(final DatePicker datePicker)
    {
        return new DateCell()
        {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty)
            {
                ...
            }
        };
    }
};
```

Is there any way by which I can also change the display text for `January`, `February`, ..., `Sat`, `Sun`, ... and `Fri` in my Jalali Calendar?

**EDIT:** here is a screenshot of what I already have. After setting the `Locale` it uses Farsi but, what I see is simply how `January` is spelled in Farsi (which is `ژانویه`). It doesn't use the actual name of the month in Jalali Calendar which is `فروردین`

[image]

Comment: hmm ... should be automatically localized. Did you try to create the DatePicker after setting the Locale? And are you sure your Locale is covered by fx resources?

Comment: I have edited my question to better answer yours. I can tell that my Locale is covered by fx resources. I have also just try to create DatePicker after setting the Locale but, I see no changes.

Comment: @kleopatra From the edit it looks like the name _is_ automatically localized but it simply translates the month's name directly from English to the desired language. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to know the chronology has entirely different names for the month. Though perhaps that's a failure in the OP's implementation of `Chronology`? I see `DatePicker` uses `Chronology#date(TemporalAccessor)` and then formats the result. But I don't know enough about the low levels of how `java.time` and formatting works to be know for sure that's a possible point of failure in this context.